# Using Pointers in functions

Tags: c++

I am trying to use a pointer in my function and then call the function from my main body. When I try to call it I get these 2 errors'; "undefined reference to string output which is caused by the line where I call my stringOutput(); function and the other error is "Id returned 1 exit status." I'm not sure why these errors are occurring.

```
void stringOutput(int dayNumber, double *ptrTemperatures);

int main()
{
    int dayNumber;
    double fahrenheit = 0;
    double cTemperature = 0;
    const double MAXIMUM_TEMPERATURE = 60;// constants for mix/max
    const double MINIMUM_TEMPERATURE = -90 ;
    const int MAXIMUM_DAYS = 365;
    const int MINIMUM_DAYS = 1;
    double *ptrTemperatures = NULL;

    cout << "How many days would you like to enter? ";
    dayNumber = myValidation::GetValidInteger(MINIMUM_DAYS, MAXIMUM_DAYS);
    try
    {
        ptrTemperatures = new double[dayNumber];
    }
    catch(exception e)
    {
        cout << "Failed to allocate memory: " << e.what() << endl;
    }
    cout << "\n\nTEMPERATURE REPORTER\n____________________________\n Please Enter the temperature for each day.";

    for(int dayCount = 0; dayCount < dayNumber; dayCount++){
        cout << "Celsius Temperature for Day " << (dayCount + 1) << ": ";
        ptrTemperatures[dayCount] = myValidation::GetValidDouble(MINIMUM_TEMPERATURE, MAXIMUM_TEMPERATURE);
    }
    stringOutput();



    delete[] ptrTemperatures;
    return 0;
}//end main

    void stringOutput(int dayNumber, double *ptrTemperatures)
    {
        cout << "DAILY TEMPERATURE REPORT\n__________________________________-\n\n";
        for(int dayCounter = 0; dayCounter < dayNumber; dayCounter++)
        {
            cout << "Day " << dayCounter << (dayCounter+1) << setw(10) << celsiusToFahrenheit(ptrTemperatures[dayCounter]) << (char(248)) << "F"
                << setw(10) << ptrTemperatures[dayCounter] << (char(248)) << "C" << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: My crystal ball (which I had to resort to because you didn't post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) is telling me that the name or signature of the declaration is different.

Comment: @chris Added all the code that is slightly relevant to the problem.

Comment: The only part I even mentioned was the declaration of `stringOutput`, and it's still missing. Judging by how you aren't passing any arguments it needs, I'd wager the missing line is `void stringOutput();`, which, of course, is not implemented anywhere.

Comment: @chris Sorry I'm new to this and I didn't really understand what you meant, but adding void to the calling statement fixed the errors but it still doesen't output the lines I have in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, your code looks roughly like this:

```
void stringOutput();

int main() 
{
    …
    stringOutput();
}

void stringOutput(int dayNumber, double *ptrTemperatures)
{
    …
}
```

Your `main` function uses the `stringOutput` function you declared above, but that function is never defined anywhere, hence the error.

Below `main`, you declare and define a separate overload of `stringOutput`, which has two parameters instead of none.

If you want to use the function you have below `main`, you need to declare it before `main`:

```
void stringOutput(int dayNumber, double *ptrTemperatures);

int main()
…
```

You also need to give it the arguments it needs, instead of giving it nothing:

```
int main()
{
    …
    stringOutput(dayNumber, ptrTemperatures);
}
```

Comment: I already have the prototype, its above main and is identical to the one below where I have all my code. As for when I add the two arguements I get the error "no matching function for call to stringOutput(etc)

Comment: @ewnf, I took your posted code, [did what you said](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f43d336a17dcf11d), and commented out some irrelevant lines. It compiles, so I don't know what to say. Again, I stress posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm baffled as to why my code won't work, I took what you linked and re added the removed code and it works fine. Regardless of whatever the problem was thank you for helping me with this :)